# AIR: Connect to database over network?

Tags: database, apache-flex, air

Is there a way to make an AIR app connect to a database over a network. I know it has a built in SQLLite but I need to connect to a database over a network. Is there anyway to do this? If not directly then maybe through the help of something else like Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The main challenge should not be the "over a network" requirement, but rather that you need an ActionScript driver for your DBMS. There are some third party libraries, e.g. [asSql](http://code.google.com/p/assql/) or [Asql](http://asql.mooska.pl/) (both for MySQL), but I have no experience with either of them.

However, depending on your application, you might really want to consider to introduce some back-end encapsulating business logic and persistence, rather than having the AIR app talk to the remote DBMS directly. Especially for multi-user apps I would definitely discourage you from doing so.. If you want to introduce a back-end, the Java platform is certainly a good choice since there are two very good AMF3 implementations ([BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/) and [GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org)). I would also recommend to take a look at the [Grails](http://grails.org) framework and especially the [Grails Flex Plugin](http://www.grails.org/Flex+Plugin). There is a nice and informative [article on InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/articles/flex-grails) about Grails and Flex.